# How to define parameters?

Tags: scala

I have following function definition:

```
  def run
  : ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, String] => String => Int => Unit =
    (store)(hostname)(port) =>
      ???
```

How to define the arguments? As you see, I tried it but it is wrong, because it is like currying, my thoughts.

Comment: `def run(store: ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, String])(hostname: String)(port: Int): Unit = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def run
 : ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, String] => String => Int => Unit =
  (store: ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, String]) => (hostname: String) => (port: Int) =>
    ???
```

Comment: Just one set of type annotations should be enough, no need to duplicate them.